# Refactor code using sed

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

How do I write a sed script the rearranges/refactors a string of characters of a file?

The contents of my file are:

```
    for(int i=0; i<old(a, 10); i++)
    {
      sum += old(c*c, i*a)
    }
```

And I want the modified contents to look like:

```
    for(int i=0; i<new(10,0,a); i++)
    {
      sum += new(i*a, c*c)
    }
```

Comment: Does the new() function take a variable number of arguments?

Comment: yes, is `new(10,0,a)` a typo?  is it supposed to be `new(10, a)`?

Comment: No, I actually wanted to know how to insert a `0` in between the 10 and a

Answer (score 3):

The following works with GNU `sed` - it makes use of the `\<` and `\>` word-boundary markers to make sure it only changes `old` to `new` when it is a "word" by itself and not just embedded as part of a word like `cold`.

```
$ sed -e 's/\<old\>/new/g' foo.c 
    for(int i=0; i<new(a, 10); i++)
    {
      sum += new(c*c, i*a)
    }
```

Use GNU sed's `-i` option if you want it to change the file in-place rather than print to stdout.

**WARNING**: This `sed` script will change **ALL** occurences of `/\<old\>/` in the source file.  This may be much more than you want to change.

Comment: i didn't notice that you wanted the arg order swapped too.  Keith Cascio's version does that.

Answer (score 2):

gnu sed:

```
/bin/sed -ire \
 's!\<old\(([^)]+), *([^) ][^)]*)\)!new(\2, \1)!g' \
 *.c </dev/null
```